# How to handle to a certain Date scenario in Selenium script

Tags: selenium

i have a scenario where on opening the calendar three dates are enabled for the current week lets' say '21,22,23' and then the next day '21' gets disabled and the next dates shown are 22 ,23 ,24 so i would like to handle this in a way so that it would pick the next date automatically the next day. I don"t want to hard code it as the script will fail next day. How should i handle this?Any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more info as : 1. What is your objective? 2. What are trying to achieve? 3. What have you tried still now? Show code 4. What worked for you? 5. Where are you stuck? 6. Provide the relevant HTML DOM.

Comment: My objective is that I have to write a selenium script and what this script does is it would pick the enabled date the next date itself or we can say it would pick the current date itself the next day when script runs.

Comment: provide answers for other questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to know the current date, and then the date of tomorrow.

This has been addressed many many times already on Stack Overflow, so search for more details. Also, this seems to be completely unrelated to Selenium, so please edit your Question and its title to correct and clarify.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
LocalDate tomorrow = today.plusDays( 1 );
```